# Can I checkout a different branch, merge, and go back to my original branch in one command?

Tags: git

I occasionally find myself doing this while doing some hotfixes on master.

```
[on master, after adding and committing a hotfix]
1. git checkout development
2. git merge master
3. git checkout master
```

Can I combine 1-3 in a single line?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't - after all, what would happen if there were merge conflicts?

On the other hand, if you want to simplify your typing, you could do 3 different *commands* on one line (and thus potentially in one bash alias or the like) via the `&&` operator:

```
git checkout development && git merge master && git checkout master
```

This will run the three commands, unless a command fails, in which case it will stop executing them.